# Does adding a second move to pokemon do anything when they are defending a gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there any benefit to leaving a Pokemon with 2 moves at a gym?  Will the AI make the better move for the situation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, at this moment, the second move does not work on gyms (if you’re defending), it only works when attacking in every setting of the game, if your Pokemon knows two moves and is defending a gym, it will use the first one it has.

Comment: And since everyone just battles their friend to quickly lose 3x a day to get a Sinnoh stone, it's not like it even matters.

Comment: Unless something has changed in the last 24 hours, this answer is incorrect. You're right that Defenders only use the first move, but Attackers can use both moves in every setting without issue. This includes Raids and Gym battles. If that's what you meant, it could be edited to clarify.

Comment: @Tylerelyt Yes, I made a mistake in explaining my answer, I have edited it.

Comment: @KimberlyW I didn't know you get a Sinnoh stone when losing 3 times a day...

Comment: @araon  there is a random chance from each battle and doesn't depend on the result of the battle

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez Sorry if I wasn't clear. I mean that it doesn't matter if you win or lose to get a Sinnoh Stone. Because of this, my coworkers just pick the weakest Pokemon (to make the match as quick as possible).